# Value being printed out side the text area

Tags: php, textarea

I have a function as such:

```
     function textarea(array $attributes){

         if(isset($attributes['name'])){
             $this->name = 'name="'.$attributes['name'].'"';
         }

         if(isset($attributes['id'])){
             $this->id = 'id="'.$attributes['id'].'"';
         }

         if(isset($attributes['class'])){
             $this->class = 'class="'.$attributes['class'].'"';
         }else{
             $this->class = 'class="aisisTextElement"';
         }

         if(isset($attributes['rows'])){
             $this->rows = 'rows="'.$attributes['rows'].'"';
         }

         if(isset($attributes['cols'])){
             $this->cols = 'cols="'.$attributes['cols'].'"';
         }

         if(isset($attributes['value'])){
             $this->value = $attributes['value'];
         }

         if(isset($attributes['style'])){
             $this->style = 'style="'.$attributes['style'].'"';
         }

         $build_aisis_element = "<textarea {$this->id} {$this->class} {$this->name} {$this->disabled}>{$this->value}</textarea>";                   
         echo $build_aisis_element;
     }
```

and every time I render it out, for example if the value was Bob Ill get something like:

```
bob
<textarea></textarea>
```

any thoughts?

I have ALL JavaScript turned so I can say with 100% accuracy its not js doing this.

**as requested.....**

Where the text area gets created

```
function aisis_custom_text(){
    $option = get_option('aisis_core');
    $aisis_form = new AisisForm();

    $aisis_form->create_aisis_form_element('label', array('value'=>'Remove the Mini   Feed(s) from the site?'));
    $aisis_form->create_aisis_form_element('textarea', array(
        'rows'=>50,
        'cols'=>50,
        'name'=>'aisis_core[404_message]',
        'value'=>get_value('404_message')
    ));
}
```

that value is just gotten through a method that goes through the options table in WordPress looking for that key - in other words in you enter test the value of the text for will be test

basically if test is put in then test is returned and the text area is populated with test

the html this renders out:

```
    test<textarea class="aisisTextElement"name="aisis_core[404_message]"rows="50"cols="50"></textarea>
```

Comment: show the code that calls this `textarea()` function

Comment: ... and show the un-rendered output, e.g. cut/paste from your browser's "view source".

Comment: ... and show the attributes handed to the function.

Comment: Updated the post - hope that helps better explain what's going on ast stated above the value function is just a function that "echos" the value we get back, so if we type test and hit save we echo back test. should that maybe be a return

Comment: What happened to the spaces? What does `var_dump($this->value)` give you right before you echo it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most likely problem is that the value contains characters that need to be escaped.

You can solve that by using:

```
     if(isset($attributes['value'])){
         $this->value = htmlspecialchars($attributes['value']);
     }
```

All strings that you output to html and that are not supposed to contain html (tags) need to be escaped that way.

Comment: the way That I solved it, but thanks for that is: return - in my value method. but I shall add your help in there too :D